# Including Fragment Indentifier with CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL?

Tags: php, curl, libcurl

I'm trying to use `CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL` to get the final redirect URL.

It works it most cases, but it appears to strip `#whatever` from the URL.

So, if this is the final URL:

```
http://example.com/?test=123#something
```

It's showing me this:

```
http://example.com/?test=123
```

Is there any way to force it to include the fragment identifier?

If not, is there any simple alternative to using `CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL` instead?

My primary goal is to get the final redirect URL and if `#uid-` is in it, I want to `echo` something - and if it doesn't exist in the URL (or if there are not any redirects), I want to `echo` something else...

Comment: If the `#..` part is being stripped, couldn't you instead treat that portion as a regular parameter? E.g. `http://example.com/?test=123&something`

Comment: I don't have control over the server that's being `curl`'d, they're the ones including `#` in it instead of making it a parameter.

Comment: By the way, I don't care about `curl` actually getting that final URL's content, I'm just wanting the URL itself.

Comment: Its an interesting question. But possibly the `#..` portion is browser specific and not apart of the url. Im just guessing tho. A question, how is that you know what the full correct url will be?

Comment: From the Location set in the response's header. It includes the `#..` portion, curl just strips it for some reason.

Comment: Fragments are not supposed to be used in HTTP requests, so they get striped out. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier#Basics